# Is it safe to remove fail2ban.git after installation?

Tags: git, github, fail2ban

I have installed [Fail2ban](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban) via:

```
git clone https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban.git
cd fail2ban
sudo python setup.py install
```

Everything works fine.

Is it now safe to remove `fail2ban.git` file from my home directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safe to remove the source directory. Installed scripts/libraries no longer need it.

PS. But why do you install from sources? Why not use your OS' package manager? `fail2ban` is quite a popular package. Package managers resolve dependencies, do proper upgrades and provide OS-dependent config files.

Anyway, if you want to install from the repository it is better to use `pip`: it does `git clone` and `setup.py install` automatically:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban.git
```

After that you can do `pip list` or `pip uninstall`.

Comment: So, just to clarify... I can remove both `fail2ban.git` file AND fail2ban directory, correct? As to why - I wasn't sure that package manager will install latest version (0.11.0.3).

Comment: 1. What is `fail2ban.git` file? `git clone` should create only `fail2ban directory`. 2. Do you really need the very latest version? Having OS package manager to install OS-specific configs and handle regular updates is more important IMO.